# How to execute continuous task in form after ShowDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I have C# application, where main form opens another form by calling ShowDialog(). I would like to have textbox in that another form with some text, which is updated once per second. Where should I put code updating text box?

I know that main form is suspended while ShowDialog is called, until it returns. So, I think code must be somewhere in the source of opened form, but how to add it there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Correct, this has nothing to do with the main form (unless the data with which to update the label originate there, which I hope is not the case... ). Have a look at the [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netcore-3.1) class.

Comment: Subscribe to `Form_Load` event.

Comment: That depends on how you are currently getting that value you need.  Do you already have code that retrieves that value somehow?  If yes, then use a Timer and pass that value to the second form.  If no, then it would make sense to put that code in the new secondary form.

Comment: Thanks Idle_mind, your comment leaded me to the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean with "other form".
Because there are multiple solutions...

**Solution A** (Its a Different FormClass so its different code)

If u have MainForm and SecondForm for example, the secondform will have different code and there you can write your Logic for that textbox..

**Solution B** (Its a Different FormClass so you have access to the Constructor)

Every Form will have a Constructor... as you are creating your form you are using the constructor..
exmpl:

```
frmSecond scnd = new frmSecond();
```

you could rewrite the constructor for the second form and pass in the TextField on create

```
frmSecond scnd = new frmSecond(textVariable);
```

**Solution C** (its actually the same Form and you reopen ur mainForm)

If this is the case, you wont have different code for the Forms. but still its possible to change variables of the other Form.

If u have a Variable for your TextField you can simply do :

```
frmMain mainForm = new frmMain();
mainForm.textVariable = "textToShow";
mainForm.showDialog();
```

**Conclusion**

There are multiple and yes very easy ways and prob even way more for a solution.
But i hope i could make you Realise what information is needed to solve a question, and that it would be way easier to Answer. As people here answer Questions with Fun and if ur Question doesnt provide information to Answer it often People will just not Answer it even if its an Easy Question.

Just Provide some Code next Time

I hope one of my Solutions could help you. Greets

Comment: Thanks for kind answer and pointing out different ways to do this! This was my first or second question on SO even I have been reading site for ages. Next time I will add code snippet, that is my learning from this question.